# How to append the rest of the rows to a second column if height is exceeded

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```html
<ul style="height:200px;width:100%;">
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
</ul>
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

This is how i want it to look:

[image]

### Notice

I am not looking for the `column-count` attribute because it divides the `ul` in 2 columns even when they all fit in 1 column. I want to push the rest of the elements that doesn't fit on the first column, to a second column. So if the max on first column is 10, and i have 15 rows, i want 10 on first and 5 on second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul style="height:200px;width:100%;">
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
</ul>
```